# How to use a Qt Quick 2 Extension Plugin on .qml with qmlscene (or qmlviewer5)

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, qml, qt5

I was create a test plugin as the Qt5/QML shared library using project templete "Libraries/Qt Quick 2 Extension Plugin" in QtCreator. My developing environment is linux with Qt-5.0.0 and QtCreator-2.6(detail is append in the bottom).

The source files (on gist): https://gist.github.com/4467883

The source files are **default generated without any changes**. The Project name is "untitled", the uri is "com.mycompany.mycomponents" and the Object Class-name is "MyItem". The source  files in "/tmp/untitled" as a SRCDIR.

And build it to output library file as *"libuntitled.so"*, *"qmldir"* and some object files in "/tmp/untitled-build" as a DESTDIR.

```
$ ls /tmp/untitled-build
Makefile  libuntitled.so  moc_myitem.cpp 
moc_myitem.o  moc_untitled_plugin.cpp  moc_untitled_plugin.o  myitem.o
qmldir  untitled_plugin.o
```

**But, I cannot use the library** at "/tmp/test/test.qml" as the test QML source with *qmlscene* command.

```
$ mkdir /tmp/test; cd /tmp/test
$ vim test.qml
```

"test.qml" (on gist): https://gist.github.com/4474422

```
$ qmlscene test.qml
```

It's **fail**, and **QML_IMPORT_TRACE** log is:

```
QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "/usr/lib64/qt5/qml"
QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "/usr/bin"
QQmlImports(file:///tmp/test/test.qml)::addImplicitImport
QQmlImports(file:///tmp/test/test.qml)::addLibraryImport: "QtQuick" 2.0 as ""
QQmlImports(file:///tmp/test/test.qml)::importExtension: loaded "/usr/lib64/qt5/qml/QtQuick.2/qmldir"
QQmlImportDatabase::importPlugin: "QtQuick" from "/usr/lib64/qt5/qml/QtQuick.2/libqtquick2plugin.so"
file:///tmp/test/test.qml:2 module "com.mycompany.mycomponents" is not installed
```

And try "-I" option:

```
$ qmlscene test.qml -I /tmp/untitled-build
```

That's **fail** too. log is:

```
QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "/usr/lib64/qt5/qml"
QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "/usr/bin"
QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "/tmp/untitled-build"
QQmlImports(file:///tmp/test/test.qml)::addImplicitImport
QQmlImports(file:///tmp/test/test.qml)::addLibraryImport: "QtQuick" 2.0 as ""
QQmlImports(file:///tmp/test/test.qml)::importExtension: loaded "/usr/lib64/qt5/qml/QtQuick.2/qmldir"
QQmlImportDatabase::importPlugin: "QtQuick" from "/usr/lib64/qt5/qml/QtQuick.2/libqtquick2plugin.so"
file:///tmp/test/test.qml:2 module "com.mycompany.mycomponents" is not installed
```

And try with "/tmp/test/qmldir":

```
$ vim /tmp/test/qmldir
```

"tmp/test/qmldir" (on gist): https://gist.github.com/4474497

That's **fail**. log:

```
QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "/usr/lib64/qt5/qml"
QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "/usr/bin"
QQmlImports(file:///tmp/test/test.qml)::addImplicitImport
QQmlImports(file:///tmp/test/test.qml)::importExtension: loaded "/tmp/test/qmldir"
QQmlImportDatabase::importPlugin: ".tmp.test" from "/tmp/untitled-build/libuntitled.so"
Module '.tmp.test' does not contain a module identifier directive - it cannot be protected from external registrations.
QQmlImports(file:///tmp/test/test.qml)::addLibraryImport: "QtQuick" 2.0 as ""
QQmlImports(file:///tmp/test/test.qml)::importExtension: loaded "/usr/lib64/qt5/qml/QtQuick.2/qmldir"
QQmlImportDatabase::importPlugin: "QtQuick" from "/usr/lib64/qt5/qml/QtQuick.2/libqtquick2plugin.so"
file:///tmp/test/test.qml:2 module "com.mycompany.mycomponents" is not installed
```

How to use the library("/tmp/untitled-build/libuntitled.so") in the test .qml("/tmp/test.qml") with qmlscene (or qmlviewer5)?

Environment detail (based on openSUSE-12.2):

```
$ uname -a
Linux LH-MAIN 3.4.11-2.16-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Sep 26 17:05:00 UTC 2012 (259fc87) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ g++ --version | head -n1
g++ (SUSE Linux) 4.7.1 20120723 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 189773]
$ qmake -v            
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.0.0 in /usr/lib64
$ qtcreator -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep "^[^ ].*" | head -n1
Qt Creator 2.6.1 based on Qt 5.0.0
$ qmlviewer5 -v    
Qml debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment!
Qt QML Viewer version 5.0.0
```

References:

1. http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qtcore/plugins-howto.html
2. http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qtcore/qtplugin.html
3. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html
4. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/examples-quick-tutorials-extending-chapter6-plugins.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to put your `plugin.so` and the `qmldir` file in a folder like:

```
- myproject
    - imports
        - com
            - mycompany
                - mycomponents
                    - libuntitled.so
                    - qmldir
```

then add the `imports` directory to the `QML2_IMPORT_PATH` environment variable.
`export QML2_IMPORT_PATH=/path/to/myproject/imports`
this worked for me on my linux box.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Important points are (1) set the environment variable 'QML2_IMPORT_PATH' and (2) set the import directory tree structure linked to the component uri. It can run on my environment.